# Can't use AVX intrinsic ,because my function compiled without support for 'xsave'

Tags: xcode, macos, avx

I want to use AVX intrinsic, like: 
__m256 factor_min = _mm256_set1_ps(1.329227);
but I got the following compile error:

> Always_inline function '_mm256_set1_ps' requires target feature 'xsave', but would be inlined into function 'AveragePooling' that is compiled without support for 'xsave'

My environment is：MacOs + Intel Core i7 + xcode8.3
[image]
I have seen other discussion about 'xsave'.But still don't know how to fix this compile error.I know nothing about assembly instructions.Is there any easy way to fix this error(maybe just change xode setting?)? Thanks a lot.

I think Intel Core i7 can totally support AVX.

Comment: "Core i7" is nearly-meaningless marketing speak. Intel started using that term with Nehalem, which didn't have AVX.

Comment: Thanks, but I still confused. I installed a win7 virtual machine in my Mac, and created a vs2013 project with AVX intrinsic. It seems good, no this compile error in vs2013, project can output right result. If Core i7 didn't have AVX, why AVX intrinsic can run in the win7 virtual machine?

Comment: You're completely missing the point.  Some core i7 CPUs have AVX (Sandybridge and alter), but Nehalem core i7 doesn't.  So no, "core i7" does not imply AVX, but it doesn't rule it out either.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same compilation issue on Xcode 9.2 on a 2017 MacBook Pro - which supports up to AVX2.

I was able to get it to compile by manually configuring the AVX vector extensions, instead of using "Platform Default".

[image]

To find out whether your CPU supports AVX, check the output of the following command in a terminal to see if it shows AVX or even AVX2:

`sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features`

Answer (score 1):

Just an update - both my Macs only showed AVX1.0 from sysctl, but in XCode 10.3, I was able to search the target settings for vector and under "Enable Additional Vector Extensions" select AVX 2, which according to Intel these Macs DO support - and it worked. :)

Update2:  Due to a quirk in Clang, not all of AVX 2 is enabled, so to get FMA support, I had to go into Build Phases->Compile Sources and add the flag -mfma.  Then I got fma instructions to compile.  Note that it looks like this process has to be done for each source file.

Comment: FMA isn't part of AVX2, it's a separate extension.  AMD Piledriver/Steamroller all have FMA3 + AVX1, with no AVX2.  (Bulldozer itself only has FMA4; Intel changed their ISA-extension plans and didn't tell AMD until it was too late.)  Compile with `-march=haswell -mno-avx2` if you care about being able to run there. And unfortunately there *is* a real-life CPU with AVX2 but not FMA3:  Via Isaiah C4650.  Some of the Via CPU architects are annoyed that they let this happen:  [CLANG optimizing using SVML and it's autovectorization](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/92123879)

Comment: Of course if you're building Mac binaries, then outside of Hackintosh like https://amd-osx.com/ or emulators, you will always find AVX2 with FMA and vice versa, and **thus you should use `-march=haswell -O3`** to *tune* for HSW as well as enabling FMA + BMI.  Virtualization could pass through one but not the other feature bit, but it can't stop FMA instructions from executing if the underlying HW supports it without also stopping all AVX1 / AVX2 instructions from working.  (By disabling the control-register bit that indicates the OS knows it needs to save YMM upper halves on context switches.)

Comment: Thanks, Peter - that's really great info!  One point that deserves attention is that compiling is just one part of the process - it's probably also important to have dynamic platform checks that choose the correct code at runtime?

Comment: Yup, if you want to distribute your binary to other systems, not just use it on your own computer.  OS X supports fat binaries that have Haswell vs. baseline x86-64 slices.  [Mac OSX minumum support sse version](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/78801833)